# I am searching for an example in C for using pkcs#5

Tags: c, security, hash, pkcs#5

AFAIK, PKCS#5 is used for hashing passwords. I could not find an example to explain how to use openssl to make a client for hashing the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

i have made a blogpost siting how to hash using openssl in C. Here is the [link](http://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/one-way-hash-functions-openssl/). Let me know, if this is the one you are looking for?